# Where can I find industry postdoc hiring statistics for Canada?

Tags: postdocs, industry, reference-request, canada

Could anyone help me with the data of hired postdocs in company and private sector in Canada? I want to find out the number and the rate of the industrial postdocs in Canada (including the postdocs in university, company, government, etc) in recent years, which is important to my research.

Answer (score 1):

[Mitacs](http://www.mitacs.ca/en) provides information (data will need to be compiled) about number of fellowships, participating institutions, expenditures, and so forth on its [reports page](http://www.mitacs.ca/en/about-mitacs/annual-reports).

However, I do not believe that Mitacs has historically been the only source of grants. See [this](http://sciencecareers.sciencemag.org/career_magazine/previous_issues/articles/2005_05_06/nodoi.2415721452983205400) article in Science (2005) and [this](http://www.nserc-crsng.gc.ca/Students-Etudiants/PD-NP/Industrial-Industrielle_eng.asp) notice from the NSERC.